# Ext js package build

Tags: javascript, extjs

Sencha command let you easily create, build and distribute your own package. Ext js library is built using sencha command.

I wonder what is the correct way to have the built-package to have everything in correct order, especially for a list of Singleton files that are in the root folder and there is no dependency among each other. For example, for sencha core package, there is Ext.js, ComponentQuery.js, etc., how Sencha command knows to always build Ext.js first.

This is a bit puzzling to me. I have a similar situation. I have a package, let's call it MyCoolStuff, in its root source folder, I have CoolStuff.js and a list of singleton/utility files, for example, CoolStuffEventHandler.js. I absolutely need CoolStuff.js to be built first, but so far have no luck.

How did ext js do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you define your classes, no matter singletones or not, you specify dependencies using [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires) and [`uses`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-uses) directives:

```
Ext.define('CoolStuffEventHandler', {
    ////
    requires: [
        'CoolStuff'
    ],
    /////
});
```

That's all! All the rest is taken care of by Sencha CMD for you.

Comment: no, there is no such dependency as i have said. Check Sencha core package, ComponentManager, Ext.define('Ext.ComponentManager', {
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.ComponentMgr',
    
    singleton: true,

Comment: It is indeed true that `Ext.ComponentManager` is not explicitly declared dependent on anything else and therefore Sencha build process must be using some other means to enforce correct inclusion order. However, is there any reason to necessarily use that "low level" way whatever it is? You said *"I absolutely need CoolStuff.js to be built first"*: as far as a developer is concerned, this is perfectly achieved by declaring dependencies, isn't it?

Comment: no, i want to do it the right way. For  any package, it must have a root file as such. Be it Coolstuff.js, or Ext.js, or MyCompany.js, it is like the app.js for an application. it is the shoe string for a package, the question is, what do i do, or where does sencha to look for this piece of crucial information

Comment: You say you want it to do the right way. What @DrakeES proposed is the right way. Use `requires`.